# RavenDB - building dynamic queries

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, nosql, ravendb

I am building a simple CMS with .NET MVC and RavenDB and i need to filter pages with x amount of incoming parameters.

Example Page:

```
public class Page{
string Name
string Content
List<string> Tags
//etc...
}
```

In my pages controller i have this method and i want to get all the pages that have matching tags. they must be excluding filter so it is an AND condition that should be added

```
public ActionResult Index(List<string> tagFilters)
{
    var pages = MyRavenSession.Query<Page>().Where( how to compare tagFilters List to pages Tags List? ) 

    return View(pages);
}
```

I have been searching the internet for answers on this scenario and there should be others that have the same problem.

How should i solve this?

I read that predicatebuilder could not be translated to RavenDB LINQ queries.

I also read that you could build some kind of RavenDB lucene query but i cannot find any examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by using `Session.Advanced.LuceneQuery()` it allows fine grained dynamic query building